# How to create css radio button in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have created a web application using asp.net and I am trying to decorate the radio button using css like below:

[image]

But after designing like this the radio buttons are not working any more. Those buttons are getting disabled. Here is my code:

```
  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rdbSMSType" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection
   ="Horizontal" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rdbSMSType_SelectedIndexChanged" >
   <asp:ListItem Value="SMS" Selected="True">SMS</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="MMS">MMS</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

CSS:

```
   input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
    }

    input[type=radio] + label, input[type=checkbox] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:-2px;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#fff),to(#e6e6e6));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff',endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6',GradientType=0);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

 input[type=radio]:checked + label, input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
       background-image: none;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.15),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
        background-color:#e0e0e0;
}
```

Please suggest me on this.

Comment: Can you show the HTML that is generated?

Comment: It works for me (Firefox and Chrome) when I change the selection. Clicking the selected button does not trigger a postback however, but that is the normal behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it works in my system (Firefox). Just in case hide your radio and checkboxes in a different way.

```
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
}
```